# Lazy Loading Components Changes CSS Stylesheet order

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm trying to add lazy loading code-splitting into my React application. I want to split components based on routes.

To do so, I added the following code:

```
const HomePage = lazy(() => import('./pages/Home'));
```

to replace my static import:

```
import HomePage from './pages/Home';
```

In my `App.js` (where I define my routes), I'm importing the following files:

```
import './App.css';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import './css/global.css';
import './index.css';
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';
```

I noticed that the CSS ordering has changed, after I added the lazy loading:

Without Lazy Loading:

```css
element.style {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    min-width: 100%;
}
<style>
.ifqsib {
    font-weight: 700;
    --text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(190,32,69,var(--text-opacity));
}
h5 {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
    font-weight: 700!important;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    line-height: 1.28571429em;
    margin: calc(2rem - 0.14286em) 0 1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: revert;
}
a, b, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif!important;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
blockquote, dd, dl, figure, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, p, pre {
    margin: 0;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

[image: Without Lazy Loading]

With Lazy Loading:

[image: With Lazy Loading]

```css
lement.style {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    min-width: 100%;
}
<style>
.sDyco {
    font-weight: 700;
    --text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(190,32,69,var(--text-opacity));
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
blockquote, dd, dl, figure, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, p, pre {
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    line-height: 1.28571429em;
    margin: calc(2rem - 0.14286em) 0 1rem;
    padding: 0;
}
a, b, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif!important;
}

h5 {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.67em 0;
    font-weight: 700!important;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: revert;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

As you can see, the `global.css` style is not applied anymore to the element. Instead, it is replaced by the `base.css`. I'm not sure why this is happening, however I would like to preserve the original styling that I have without lazy loading components.